# Pregunta sobre MongoDB y NodeJS

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

Estoy entrenando MongoDB y NodeJS, aunque me surgen algunas dudas.
En mi archivo de APP definí lo siguiente

Aquí les pongo mi código (no le hagan caso a las notas XD)

```
//esta variable almacena las funciones del paquete express, el cuál es el núcleo del framework
var express = require('express');

//esta variable almacena las funciones de la variable express, el cual le da vida a la página
var app = express();

//esta variable almacena las funciones del paquete mongoose el cual sirve para conectarse con MongoDB
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//esta variable almacena las funciones del paquete body-parser, el cual sirve para traducir las peticiones en json
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//esta variable almacena las funciones del paquete cloudinary, el cual sirve para subir imagenes a la web
var cloudinary = require('cloudinary');

//esta variable almacena las funciones del paquete multer, el cual sirve para hacer más legibles de código las imágenes
var multer = require('multer');

//Se realiza la configuración de cloudinary con nuestra cuenta
cloudinary.config(
{
        cloud_name:"***",
        api_key:"***",
        api_secret:"***"
});

//Aquí le decimos que se conecte a mongo, la ruta por defecto es esta.
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myPage');

//Aquí le indicamos a app que use las funciones de bodyParser.
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Aquí le indicamos que desencripte la información enviada por POST o GET
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

//Aqui mencionamos que habrá una carpeta de archivos estaticos.
app.use(express.static("public"));

//Le indicamos a Express que use a multer con los parámetros, de donde se subiran las imágenes y su será una sola, un array o ocualquiera.
app.use(multer({dest: "./uploads"}).single('image_avatar'));

//se creará un nuevo esquema de productos, es decir, el esqueleto del documento JSON
var productosSchema =
{
    title:String,
    desc:String,
    imageUrl:String,
    price:Number
};

//Creamos una nueva variable la cual
var Product = mongoose.model("Product", productosSchema);

//se indica a la aplicación que jade será será el motor de vistas
app.set("view engine", "jade");

/*get es el método HTTP, también se usa POST pero eso es usado cuando
se hacen envíos de formulario. El primer parámetro es conocer a cuál
URL esta haciendo la petición, en este caso es la raíz. El segundo
es la respuesta del servidor*/
app.get("/", function(req,res)
{
    //se renderiza el index, el cual es el jade en views
    res.render('index');
});

//renderiza el archivo new.jade y nos dá la descripción del body enviado
app.post("/menu", function(req,res)
{

    //Aquí se crean los datos para la DB respetando el esqueleto que se definió arriba
    //la información la sacamos del request y después de body y luego de cada campo
    var data =
    {
        title : req.body.name,
        desc : req.body.desc,
        imageUrl : "",
        price : req.body.price
    }

    //se crea una nueva variable y se estancia del modelo definido arriba y se envían los datos.
    var product = new Product(data);

    //se usa la sentencia de claudinary para subir las fotos.
    cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path,
    function(result)
    {
        //antes de guardar el JSON en MongoDB, le decimos que la url viene del result
        product.imageUrl = result.url;
        product.save(function(err)
        {
            console.log(result);
            console.log(product);
            res.render("menu/new");
        });
    });
});
//Se salva la información y se manda un mensaje a la consola.


//Renderiza el archivo new.jade
app.get("/menu/new",function(req,res)
{
    res.render("menu/new");
});

app.get("/menu",function(req,res)
{
    Product.find(function(error,document)
    {
        if(error)
        {
            console.log(error);
        }

        else
        {
            res.render("menu/index",{productos : document})
        }
    });
});

//Aquí se define cual es el puerto de escucha.
port = 3000;
app.listen(port);
console.log("Servidor corriendo en el puerto " + port);
```

Mi pregunta es, Cuando metí datos a Mongo lo hizo de maravilla, aunque yo no tenía esa Colección "Product" me creo una colección llamada products, que en ningún lado del código definí como una nueva colección.
Eso me confunde mucho, alguien me puede ayudar a decirme como funciona eso?

Además cuando quiero traer los datos de Mongo tengo que usar la sentencia `Product.find()` por que si la uso como `products.find()` me marca un error. A lo que me refiero es que, no se supone que tengo que hacer los queries tal y como lo escribiría en Mongo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los drivers de Mongodb de los distintos lenguajes, se preocupan de la creación de la colección en el caso que no exista. Es por ello que cuando te conectaste, el driver buscó tu colección y al no encontrarla, la creó de forma transparente.

Respecto al método `find`, esto es relativo a la API de mongoose. Al hacer

```
var Product = mongoose.model("Product", productosSchema);
```

creas una clase `Product` la cual cuenta con métodos estáticos, los cuales hacen llamadas a mongo. Si hicieses `products.find` estarías llamando al método `find` de un array de productos.

Comment: Pero por que products.find
No sería Product.find?
Digo, por que así lo declaré como clase.

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob estoy diciendo justamente lo contrario. Debe usar `Product.find` no `products.find`

Comment: Creo que no me he especificado del todo bien, me refiero a que, yo en ningún lado del código declare products, declaré Product que es diferente. Mi pregunta es, por qué la colección en Mongo se llama products si yo no declaré nada con ese nombre,

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob ahora comprendo tu pregunta. Comúnmente, es recomendable crear las tablas/colecciones de las BD como el plural de el 'objeto' que representan. Es por esto que mongoose pluraliza el schema que le indicaste mira acá http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection donde puedes poner el nombre que quieras.

Comment: ¡Denle una cerveza! Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Un ejemplo de una búsqueda con mongoose, primero te dejo la estructura json de la colección:
{id:'id',
attribs: {
nombre: 'nombre',
categorías: 'categoria',
detalles: 'detalles'
}}

```
products.find({attribs: {$elemMatch: {categoria : "bebidas"}}}, function (err, products){

}
```